# How to convert Multidimensional int Array to a String List?

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist, multidimensional-array, type-conversion

### MultiDimensional 2D int array to string List

---

I would like to convert my array2D:

```
int[,] array2D = new int[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };
```

to a List:

```
List<String> numbers = new List<string>(array2d.ToString());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can flatten a multi-dimensional array with `Enumerable.Cast`

```
List<String> number = array2D.Cast<int>().Select(i => i.ToString()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert 2d array into jagged array and then convert it to List.

```
int[,] arr = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };

int[][] jagged = new int[arr.GetLength(0)][];

for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
{
jagged[i] = new int[arr.GetLength(1)];
for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
{
    jagged[i][j] = arr[i, j];
}
}

List<int[]> list = jagged.ToList();
```